# Dice game for two players (Nea)

Tags: python, dice

The rules:

- The points rolled on each player’s dice are added to their score.
- If the total is an even number, an additional 10 points are added to their score.
- If the total is an odd number, 5 points are subtracted from their score.
- If they roll a double, they get to roll one extra die and get the number of points rolled added to their score.
- The score of a player cannot go below 0 at any point.
- The person with the highest score at the end of the 5 rounds wins.
- If  both  players  have  the  same  score  at  the  end  of  the  5  rounds,  they  each  roll  1  die  and  whoever gets the highest score wins (this repeats until someone wins)

```
import pickle
import random
import time

print("")
print("welcome to the dice game")
print("")

with open('users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    users = pickle.load(f)

print(users)


def login():

    logged_in = False

    username = input('please enter username: ')

    while not logged_in:

        if username in users:
            password = input("enter password: ")
            if password == users[username]:
                print("access granted")
                logged_in = True

        else:
            print("access denied")
            exit()

    return username


print("  ")

rounds = 0


def roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 7)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 7)
    change = 10 if (die1 + die2) % 2 == 0 else -5
    points = die1 + die2 + change
    if die1 == die2:
        points += random.randint(1, 6)
    return points


def game():
    player1_points = 0
    player2_points = 0
    for i in range(1, 6):
        player1_points += roll()
        print(f'After this round user1 you now have: {player1_points} Points')
        # time.sleep(1)
        player2_points += roll()
        print(f'After this round user2 you now have: {player2_points} Points')

    player1_tiebreaker = 0
    player2_tiebreaker = 0
    if player1_points == player2_tiebreaker:
        while player1_tiebreaker == player2_tiebreaker:
            player1_tiebreaker = random.randint(1, 6)
            player2_tiebreaker = random.randint(1, 6)

    player2_win = (player2_points + player2_tiebreaker)
    player1_win = (player1_points + player1_tiebreaker) \

    return (player1_points, player1_win), (player2_points, player2_win)


def add_winner(winner):

    with open('Winner.txt', 'a') as i:
        i.write(','.join(map(str, winner)))
        i.write('\n')


def get_leaderboard():
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r+') as g:
        return [line.replace('\n', '') for line in g.readlines()]


def update_leaderboard(leaderboard, winner):
    for idx, item in enumerate(leaderboard):
        if item.split(',')[1] == winner[1] and int(item.split(',')[0]) < int(winner[0]):
            leaderboard[idx] = '{}, {}'.format(winner[0], winner[1])
        else:
            pass
    leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)


def save_leaderboard(leaderboard):
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r+') as h:
        for item in leaderboard:
            h.write(f'{item}\n')


def main():
    user1 = login()
    user2 = login()

    (player1, player1_win), (player2, player2_win) = game()

    if player1_win:
        winner = [player1, user1]
    else:
        winner = [player2, user2]

    print("Well done: ", winner[1], "you won with", winner[0], "Points")

    add_winner(winner)
    leaderboard = get_leaderboard()
    update_leaderboard(leaderboard, winner)
    save_leaderboard(leaderboard)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting off, its not secure the way you are prompting for passwords and storing them. Instead, use the `getpass` module, and store the hash of the password. I'm not even certain that this way is 100% correct (I'm not a security guru), but its what the Python documentation shows for secure password hashing, and I imagine its better than plaintext.

```
from getpass import getpass
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac as pwhash

def login(users):
    username = input('please enter username: ')
    if not username in users:
        print("access denied")
        exit()

    password_hash = None
    while password_hash != users[username]:
        password_hash = pwhash("sha256", getpass().encode("ascii"), b"t4h20p8g24j", 100000)

    print("access granted")
    return username
```

Your roll function had a typo in it-  the third (optional) roll could only generate numbers [1, 5] inclusive. I also reordered the statements to remove an intermediate variable that didn't contribute anything.

```
def roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1, 7)
    die2 = random.randint(1, 7)
    points = die1 + die2
    points += 10 if (die1 + die2) % 2 == 0 else -5
    if die1 == die2:
        points += random.randint(1, 7)
    return points
```

I would replace your `get_leaderboard` body with a shorter and cleaner read call.

```
def get_leaderboard():
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r+') as g:
        return g.read().split("\n")
```

And similarly for `save_leaderboard`

```
def save_leaderboard(leaderboard):
    with open('Leaderboard.txt', 'r+') as h:
        h.write("\n".join(leaderboard))
```

You should also try to avoid excessive use of tuples when you need to access the elements individually. Your code will be littered with `thingy[0]` and `thingy[1]` and nobody but you (if that) will know what the significance of `0` and `1` are. I revised `update_leaderboard` with these changes, but I'm still not quite satisfied with it.

```
def update_leaderboard(leaderboard, winner):
    winner_score, winner_name = winner
    for idx, item in enumerate(leaderboard):
        item_score, item_name = item.split(', ')
        if item.name == winner_name and int(item_score) < int(winner_score):
            leaderboard[idx] = '{}, {}'.format(winner_score, winner_name)
    leaderboard.sort(reverse=True)
    #leaderboard.sort(reverse=True), key=lambda x:int(x.split(', ')[0]))
```

The data really shouldn't be cast back and forth from strings to lists/tuples so much. It would be best to just make a dictionary of `name:score` pairs, and write a tiny bit of formatting logic into your `get_leaderboard` and `save_leaderboard` functions. I wasn't going to change that much though.

I also want to point out common mistake that could normally create a bug in sorting (in your case it does not because of the hard-coded `,`, but still)-  you can't rely on `str.sort` to sort a list of strings by their numerical value. I left a comment showing how you would do this correctly if your delimiter evaluated as greater than `"0"`.

Furthermore- you shouldn't really rely on changing `leaderboard` outside the function scope. I feel like this is partially why you chose to go with the (unnecessary) `enumeration()` logic. Instead, return the modified leaderboard and allow the caller to take it from there.

Anyways, the last major change I would make would be to move all your globals (and friends) inside your `main()` function.

```
def main():
    print("")
    print("welcome to the dice game")
    print("")

    with open('users.pickle', 'rb') as f:
        users = pickle.load(f)

    print(users)
    print("  ")

    user1 = login(users)
    user2 = login(users)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks and about the security its just a game so I didn't want it to complicated but still nice to know.